# variance and consistency of a statistics

Tags: statistics, variance, mean-square-error

To study the mean of a population variable $X$, $\mu = E(X)$, a simple random
sample of size $n$ is considered. Imagine that we do not trust the first and
the last data, so we consider the following statistics:

$\sim X$ = $\frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} Xj$ = $\frac{X_2+....X_{n-1}}{n-2}$

Calculate the expectation and the variance of this statistic. Calculate the
mean square error (MSE) and its limit when $n$ tends to infinite. Study the
consistency. Compare the previous error with that of the ordinary sample
mean.

I calculated the expectation of this statistic doing : $E(\sim X)$ = $\frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} Xj$ = $\frac{(n-2)\mu}{n-2} = \mu$

I do not know how to find out the variance of this statistics and consequently how to continue the exercise.

Any help, suggestion would be appreciate

Comment: When you say  "do not trust the first and the last data" do you mean the lowest and highest values or the earliest and latest values?   If you are excluding the  earliest and latest values, then this is equivalent to the the variance of the sample mean but with $n-2$ observations instead of $n$

Comment: yes I mean the earliest and the latest so the variance is equal simply to $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: So usually what is the variance of the sample mean?

Comment: $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ so in this case should be $\frac{\sigma^2}{n-2}$ ?

Comment: Indeed I suspect so

Comment: and so MSE ($\sim X)$<MSE($\bar X)$ because $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}<\frac{\sigma^2}{n-2}$   Am I correct?